# How to change Steps Color in ( Ant-design )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ant-design-pro

I am new to Ant-design. Currently I am working on ReactJs project and I've used `Steps` in my project. I want to change the color of `Steps` but did not get idea how will it be possible . I will share ant-design (`Steps`) code. Please help me out 
Thanks

You may see example of `Steps` in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4zxzpnrok0)

**Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Steps, Button, message } from 'antd';

const Step = Steps.Step;

const steps = [{
  title: 'First',
  content: 'First-content',
}, {
  title: 'Second',
  content: 'Second-content',
}, {
  title: 'Last',
  content: 'Last-content',
}];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      current: 0,
    };
  }

  next() {
    const current = this.state.current + 1;
    this.setState({ current });
  }

  prev() {
    const current = this.state.current - 1;
    this.setState({ current });
  }

  render() {
    const { current } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Steps current={current}>
          {steps.map(item => <Step key={item.title} title={item.title} />)}
        </Steps>
        <div className="steps-content">{steps[current].content}</div>
        <div className="steps-action">
          {
            current < steps.length - 1
            && <Button type="primary" onClick={() => this.next()}>Next</Button>
          }
          {
            current === steps.length - 1
            && <Button type="primary" onClick={() => message.success('Processing complete!')}>Done</Button>
          }
          {
            current > 0
            && (
            <Button style={{ marginLeft: 8 }} onClick={() => this.prev()}>
              Previous
            </Button>
            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: How to update tail color ?

Comment: @AjitTStephen i put my answer

Comment: @AmitKadivar thanks, for idea. a small change and it works, look https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-snowflake-mqvi1

Answer (score 2):

Use **inline styles**.

**Code**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Steps, Button, message } from "antd";

const Step = Steps.Step;

const steps = [
  {
    title: "First",
    content: "First-content"
  },
  {
    title: "Second",
    content: "Second-content"
  },
  {
    title: "Last",
    content: "Last-content"
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      current: 0
    };
  }

  next() {
    const current = this.state.current + 1;
    this.setState({ current });
  }

  prev() {
    const current = this.state.current - 1;
    this.setState({ current });
  }

  render() {
    const { current } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Steps current={current} style={{ "background-color": "blueviolet" }}>
          {steps.map(item => (
            <Step key={item.title} title={item.title} />
          ))}
        </Steps>
        <div className="steps-content" style={{ "background-color": "grey" }}>
          {steps[current].content}
        </div>
        <div className="steps-action" style={{ "background-color": "blue" }}>
          {current < steps.length - 1 && (
            <Button
              type="primary"
              style={{ "background-color": "red" }}
              onClick={() => this.next()}
            >
              Next
            </Button>
          )}
          {current === steps.length - 1 && (
            <Button
              type="primary"
              onClick={() => message.success("Processing complete!")}
            >
              Done
            </Button>
          )}
          {current > 0 && (
            <Button style={{ marginLeft: 8 }} onClick={() => this.prev()}>
              Previous
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: Thank You for reply but i want to change the color of steps like (1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ) as you see they using default color (blue)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add following CSS

```
.ant-steps-item-process .ant-steps-item-icon { background: red; }
```

See `index.css` in this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/oomv369k36)

By the way you a have a more robust way to change ant framework styling, please refer to the [documenatation](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme)

Comment: This style use when you change tail color of steps

Answer (score 1):

if you change all your step tails color then 
put the following style in **index.css**

```
.ant-steps-item-finish
  > .ant-steps-item-container
  > .ant-steps-item-tail::after {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

change **background-color**
if you change only one step tail color then put className in `Step` like this

```
       <Steps className="custome-step" current={1} progressDot>
              <Step title="In Progress" description="Loan Application" />
              <Step title="" description="Loan Vetting" />
              <Step title="" description="Disbursement" />
       </Steps>
```

**index.css**

```
.custome-step .ant-steps-item-finish > .ant-steps-item-container > .ant-steps-item-tail::after {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-galileo-9ovtg)

Answer (score 0):

Add a span in your Step and style it or add a class name, just like this:

```
<Step title={<span className="font-bold">First content</span>} status="process"/>
```

If you want to style an indicating circle background, add it to your CSS and make sure you add !important, just like this:

```
.ant-steps-item-process .ant-steps-item-icon {
    background: #46b3cb !important;
}
```